# Convert Array CSV to Object using Header

Tags: javascript, array, csv

Takes the first array in the array and uses that to set the properties of an array-object.

```
var _ = require("underscore");
function csvToObject(data){
  var header = data.shift();
  return _.map(data, function(row){
    var temp = {};
    _.each(row, function(cell, key){
      temp[header[key]] = cell;
    });
    return temp;
  });
}
```

I created a non-underscore dep version

```
function csvToObject2(data) {
  var header = data.shift();
  var alpha = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var beta = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      beta[header[j]] = data[i][j];
    }
    alpha.push(beta);
  }
  return alpha;
};
```

They both [performed the same in jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/csv-object). Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use built-in methods such as `map` and `reduce`. According to JSPerf they are [as fast](http://jsperf.com/csv-object/2) and the code is shorter, so you could potentially get rid of the Underscore dependency:

```
function csvToObject2(data) {
  return data.slice(1).map(function(xs) {
    return xs.reduce(function(acc, x, i) {
      acc[data[0][i]] = x
      return acc
    },{})
  })
}
```